# Select rows where 3 consecutive values match condition - Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:

```
   values
0   45
1   47
2   58
3   40
4   45
5   40
6   50
7   55
8   60
9   60
10  20
...
```

I would like to obtain a dataframe containing only rows where 3 consecutive values are greater than a specific number, let's say greater than 44.
The resultin df would be:

```
  values
0   45
1   47
2   58
6   50
7   55
8   60
9   60
...
```

Please note that value=45 in index=3 has been excluded because there are no 3 consecutive values greater than 44.
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
A = 44
B = 3

m = df['values'].gt(A)
s = (~m).cumsum()[m]
df1 = df[s.map(s.value_counts()).ge(B).reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)]
print (df1)
   values
0      45
1      47
2      58
6      50
7      55
8      60
9      60
```

Explanation/details:

First compare by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater:

```
print (df['values'].gt(A))
0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4      True
5     False
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10    False
Name: values, dtype: bool
```

Then create groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with inverted mask by `~`:

```
print ((~m).cumsum())
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    3
Name: values, dtype: int32
```

Filter mask only by greater values with `m` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print ((~m).cumsum()[m])
0    0
1    0
2    0
4    1
6    2
7    2
8    2
9    2
Name: values, dtype: int32
```

Compare by second value by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for greater od equal:

```
print (s.map(s.value_counts()).ge(B))
0     True
1     True
2     True
4    False
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: values, dtype: bool
```

Last add filter out rows by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html), so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (s.map(s.value_counts()).ge(B).reindex(df.index, fill_value=False))
0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10    False
Name: values, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you want to keep a row if the 2 values before, 2 values after or one of each satisfy the condition but you can play along this line of thought of a rolling window:

```py
testVal=42
df.loc[(df['values']>testVal).rolling(3,center=True).sum()==3]
```

You might want to use a different window (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.windows.html#module-scipy.signal.windows)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
print(df[df.groupby(df['values'].gt(44).ne(df['values'].gt(44).shift()).cumsum()).transform('count').gt(1)].dropna())
```

Output:

```
   values
0    45.0
1    47.0
2    58.0
6    50.0
7    55.0
8    60.0
9    60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in df.index:

   value = df['values'][i]

   if(value > 44 and i == 0):
      print(value)
   elif(value > 44 and i > 0):    
     before = df['values'][i-1]
     after = df['values'][i+1]
     if(before > 44 and after > 44):
        print(value)
        print(before)
        print(after)
```

Please check if this helps you.